# Rename files/folders using Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, unix, rename

Would someone be able to help me with commands for Mac Terminal?

I am trying to rename multiple file and folders like this:

Folder:

```
from: somePath/20191205 to: somePath/2019-12-05
```

Files:

```
from: somePath/20191205/20191205-Name.jpg to: somePath/2019-12-05/2019-12-05-Name.jpg
```

I am trying to do this with terminal but I cannot figure out how to rename using wildcards.

In DOS, I think it would be something like

```
ren ????????*.* ????-??-??-*.*
```

Anyway, can someone help me with a way to rename these in Mac Terminal?

*** Update:

I tried the following and it does insert 1 _ (or -) but I need to insert 2 of them and have the rest of the existing filename.  Still researching, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: mv somePath/20191205/20191205-Name.jpg somePath/2019-12-05/2019-12-05-Name.jpg

Comment: Yes, but I want to do this over multiple files, I can't do each one individually.  That is why I am asking about wildcards, or another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps:

```
$ find . -type f
./20191204/20191204.a.txt
./20191204/20191204.b.txt
./20191204/20191204.d.txt
./20191204/20191204.c.txt
./20191205/20191205.c.txt
./20191205/20191205.d.txt
./20191205/20191205.b.txt
./20191205/20191205.a.txt

$ for i in `find . -type f`; do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/\.\/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\2-\3-\4\5/'`;done

$ find . -type f
./20191204/2019-12-04.a.txt
./20191204/2019-12-04.b.txt
./20191204/2019-12-04.d.txt
./20191204/2019-12-04.c.txt
./20191205/2019-12-05.b.txt
./20191205/2019-12-05.a.txt
./20191205/2019-12-05.d.txt
./20191205/2019-12-05.c.txt
```

explanation:

1. list files w/o all properties for the curr dir with its subdirs with `find . -type f`
2. move files to the same subdirs
3. list again

Comment: Excellent, that seems to work, thank you so much.  One question, what if I want this to recurse subdirectories?  Can I just add -r?  I'll try

Comment: No, mv does not have a -r flag

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but I get mv: rename ./19980318/19980318-SMPIMG03.JPG to ./1998-03-18/19980318-SMPIMG03.JPG: No such file or directory

Comment: that's because it's renaming the directory and not the file - the directories have the same naming pattern as the files do. that's the problem

Comment: @LilMoke try again, I've updated the MV line. It works now with the same patterned directories.